# how to subtract the Sundays from no of days in a month

Tags: sql, oracle

How to find out a Sundays in a month?

please help me on this..

no of Sundays : 4 for current month  and i need to subtract these count from the days in a month

::  days in a month  -sundays

If i pass the dates in between from and to i need to get the count of sundays for that period..

Many thanks for your help.

Sunitha..

Comment: `TO_CHAR` with day `format mask` will give you the day, use `CASE` to check if it is `SUNDAY` and don't include it. For more detailed answer, please provide a `test case`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select to_char(last_day(sysdate),'dd') -
    ((next_day(last_day(trunc(sysdate)),'sunday')-7
    -next_day(trunc(sysdate,'mm')-1,'sunday'))/7+1) as result
    from dual
```

For count dates between a period you can do this:

```
SELECT (next_day(TRUNC(TO_DATE('28/09/2014','DD/MM/YYYY')),'sunday') -
    next_day((trunc(TO_DATE('13/09/2014','DD/MM/YYYY'))),'sunday')-7)/7+1 AS RESULT
     FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Sorry, I put 30 in a bad place

Comment: thank you for your rply..If i pass the dates in between from and to i need to get the count of sundays for that period..

Answer (score 0):

If you have from and to dates, you should first generate all the dates between them using hierarchal query. And then filter only sundays from them.

```
select count(1)
from (
  select start_date + level - 1     as dates
  from dual
  connect by start_date + level - 1 <= end_date
  )
where to_char(dates,'fmday') = 'sunday';
```

If you want to calculate number of non sundays for current month, find the first and last day of the month and follow the same procedure as above.

```
select count(1)
from (
  select start_date + level - 1 as dates
  from (
        select trunc(sysdate,'month')   as start_date,
                last_day(sysdate) as end_date
        from dual
        )
  connect by start_date + level - 1 <= end_date
  )
where to_char(dates,'fmday') != 'sunday';
```

[Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/35401).

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT (
        (
          TO_CHAR(next_day(last_day(TRUNC(sysdate))-7,'SUN'),'DD')-
          TO_CHAR(next_day(last_day(TRUNC(sysdate-30)),'SUN'),'DD')
         )/7
        )+1
FROM dual;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply..If i pass the dates in between from and to i need to get the count of sundays for that period..please help